# pyosd works with interpreter , but not with a script

Tags: command-line, unity, scripts, python, notify-osd

I am working on a script that would display arbitrary system information on screen. For that purpose I've been trying to use `pyosd` module.

Consider the following 3 lines:

```
import pyosd
p = pyosd.osd()
p.display("ASKUBUNTU")
```

This works alright with python 2.7 interpreter, however , fails when run from a script - no exception is thrown , but nothing is displayed either.  How can I troubleshoot this ?

I am open to alternative suggestions, but `pynotify` also doesn't work for me, as the notifications it raises cannot be placed into arbitrary position of the screen.  Note also, that `gnome-osd-client` is also a useful tool, but i need a standalone script rather than using external application. The script would be aimed at other users, and i don't want them to download extra packages they won't need

Comment: Serg, Does setting `os.environ['DISPLAY']` and `os.environ['XAUTHORITY']` work?

Comment: @heemayl it does not. I've also tried settings those values from within the script - didn't help

Comment: I can't even get this example to run in 16.04 with `python-pyosd` installed. The second line gives me the error `"pyosd.error: Requested font not found"`.

Comment: @NathanOsman changing font might help ,but on 14.04 it works alright

Comment: the odd thing is that the script runs, without errors. but nothing is displayed

Comment: @Serg in 16.04, indeed "font not found". There are more mentions of the error on the web... You could however always put a 100% transparant Gtk screen with option "always on top" like here: http://askubuntu.com/a/762266/72216 All options, position etc can be defined.

Comment: ...I mean Gtk window of course, still early here. Also the advantage of being completely done by default stuff.

Comment: Found the solution !!! Will post in a minute

Comment: Just one last question, guys. I don't recall if `pyosd` was installed by default or not. Has any of you had to install it ?

Comment: Yep, wasn't here by default. Still doesn't work on 16.04 here. If it's for others, make sure they don't use 16.04.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I will try my best to find solution for that

Answer (score 1):

As stated in http://ichi2.net/pyosd/

> FAQs
>
> Why can I display text interactively, but not in a script?
>
> Text is displayed in a different thread, so you need to keep the
>   program running long enough to see the text. Usually this means adding
>   the following function call at the end of your program:
>
> my_pyosd_obj.wait_until_no_display()

Thus , the solution was to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pyosd
p = pyosd.osd( )
p.display("HELLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO")
p.show()
p.wait_until_no_display()
```

#### 16.04

The 16.04 LTS appears to have removed many of the fonts used in previous versions. After installing the x11 fonts with `sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi` and reboot, the code works with the default font which is specified in `pydoc pyosd`:

```
default_font = '-*-helvetica-medium-r-normal-*-*-360-*-*-p-*-*-*'
```

[image]

Comment: And so it does. Nice!

Comment: It seems you can *set* the font, though the format is not really clear. I managed to mess with the color though: `http://svn.pykota.com/pykota/trunk/bin/pykosd`

Comment: @JacobVlijm yes you can set the font , it is supposed to be in `X logical font description (XLFD)` style. There's also `fonts.alias` files in various folders on the system, where you can find some of the examples of it. I've been trying to find a suitable one for the past hour or two, but so far only the default works after installing the package i mentioned. As fro 14.04 , well, i managed to find 3 fonts that work, but they fail in 16.04